# Is it possible to use a batch script to launch xfce4 in WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, batch-file, autohotkey, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xfce

So I have just started using Auto Hotkeys to shortcut some things I have to do. One of these is to make Windows+Shift+L a shortcut to launch my virtual desktop.

Some notes:

- I am on Windows 10 Home (Version 2004)
- I am using WSL2
- I am using Ubuntu 20.04
- I am using XLaunch for XServer

The AHK file looks like:

```
; Global hotkeys
#+l::Run, C:\Users\conne\WSL\linuxmachine.bat
```

This file runs my batch file which is where the issues are coming from.

To get my virtual desktop to run, I have to run my XLaunch file to run XServer, then (in Ubuntu 20.04) run

```
startxfce4
```

I have tried doing this through a batch file as shown below.

```
START C:\Users\conne\WSL\XLaunch.xlaunch

wsl.exe startxfce4
```

This will start the XServer fine, but when it has to run the xfce4 startup, I get an error message:

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
```

My guess is the machine is denying me access to run the command unless I am actually using Ubuntu, instead of this method.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are not authorized to run X server. To change this, edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` so that it says:

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

After this is done, you will quite possibly encounter another problem which will say that no screens are found. I don't know if you noticed this but if you create an alias in `~/.bashrc` and try to run it with "wsl command" it will not accept it saying command not found. This means that you need to make it so that `wsl.exe` also looks at `~/.bashrc` file before executing anything, because `DISPLAY` configurations are located in that file.

I will paste the solution I found from here https://superuser.com/questions/1444767/how-to-use-alias-created-commands-with-wsl-command-wsl-ubuntu

```
wsl bash -ic command
```

So in this case it would be

```
wsl bash -ic startxfce4
```

After executing this, if display is configured properly in the .bashrc file, it should work. It worked for me anyway.